# WSoD being caused by this piece of code

Tags: php, functions, mysql, wpdb, input

This is a function I'm writing which is supposed to post an input along with some other information, to a database. As of right now, activating the plugin produces a WSoD, when the function is removed the rest of the plugin functions as intended.

This is the input:

```
 <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="' . $quanid . '" value="" class="input" />
            <button class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

$quanid is coming from a CSV file:

```
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

      $quanid = $data[2];
```

---

```
add_action('login_head','ref_access');

function ref_access(){
global $error;

if (is_user_logged_in())
$newdb = new wpdb( 'user', 'pass', 'db', 'localhost' );
global $newdb;
$hf_username = wp_get_current_user();
$inputValue = $_POST[$quanid];
$wpdb->insert( 
$table, 
array( 
    'ItemID' => $quanid
    'Price' => $inputValue
    'user' => $hf_username
), 
);

{

}else {
     $error = "Error: You must be logged in to submit prices";
     return ; 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your code formatting and syntax at the very least:

```
function ref_access(){
global $error;

if (is_user_logged_in()) // <-- problem here...
$newdb = new wpdb( 'user', 'pass', 'db', 'localhost' );
global $newdb;
$hf_username = wp_get_current_user();
$inputValue = $_POST[$quanid];
$wpdb->insert( 
$table, 
array( 
    'ItemID' => $quanid
    'Price' => $inputValue
    'user' => $hf_username
), 
);

{ // <-- problem here...

}else {
     $error = "Error: You must be logged in to submit prices";
     return ; 
     }
}
```

Correctly formatted:

```
function ref_access(){

    global $error;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        global $newdb;

        //you are not using $newdb anywhere in this functions
        $newdb = new wpdb( 'user', 'pass', 'db', 'localhost' );

        $hf_username = wp_get_current_user();
        $inputValue  = $_POST[$quanid];

        //you need to delcare global $wpdb here if you plan to use $wpdb instead of $newdb
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $table, //there is no $table variable within this function
            array( 
                'ItemID' => $quanid
                'Price'  => $inputValue
                'user'   => $hf_username
            )
        );

    } else {
         $error = "Error: You must be logged in to submit prices";
         return; 
    }

}
```

## Update:

With regards to your comment about `$table` being defined in another function, you need to then pass the valuue `$table` to your function call `ref_action('my_table_name')`.

Example:

```
function ref_access($table = '') {
  //function code
}

//Usage

ref_access('my_table_name');
```

Comment: Hmm, still not working, I changed the one usage of `$wpdb` to `$newdb`. I think the problem may be that `$quanid` and `$table` are defined in another function, and I'm unaware of how to connect the two.

Comment: Where are you calling `ref_access()` from? You should pass `$table` to `ref_access($table)` but don't forget to add `$table` variable to the function definition.

Comment: OH! I just realized, the example I was using, where `ref_access` came from, had the `add_action` reference as part of it. 

I don't have a hook named `login_head`, what should I be using for my hook?

Comment: Try `add_action('init', `ref_access`)`, you still need to get a handle on your `$table` variable though. I have no idea what your overall code looks like. Paste a copy to pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/28na7bLC

Comment: Alright, in the past few hours I discovered wp_debug, and some other debugging tools, and have solved a few of the problems I was having. Now my only issue seems to be the table name, I'm getting this error: `WordPress database error: [Incorrect table name '']
INSERT INTO `` (`ItemID`,`Price`,`user`) VALUES ('','','')`

Comment: @Kreation You need to pass the table name to your `ref_access` function. Since you are calling this function on a hook, you can either hard-code the table name into the function, or pass the table name as a `$_POST` array key (insecure). If you have no other logical way to get the table name and you have more than one table, send a hidden field from your form with a non-obvious name and value and use that value to lookup the table name held within an array of table names inside your `ref_access` function. Come see us in [chat] if you are still having problems.